# Can @ManagedPropery and @PostConstruct be placed in a base class?

Tags: jsf-2, subclass, managed-bean, postconstruct, managed-property

I'm using a hierarchy of classes and what I would optimally try to do is have `@ManagedBean`'s that inherit a class that have `@ManagedProperty` members and `@PostConstruct` methods.

Specifically, will this work? :

```
public class A {

    @ManagedProperty
    private C c;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Do some initialization stuff
    }

    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class B extends A {
    // Content...
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I have a similar set-up that uses CDI and EJB injection in the superclass and the injected objects are used by subclasses. My superclass is `@SessionScoped` and the subclasses are `@ViewScoped`.  I have `@PostConstruct` in the superclass and in the subclasses as well. All is working fine. However, I don't know how `@ManagedProperty` injection will behave in this set-up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `@ManagedProperty` is inherited and will just work that way. The `@PostConstruct` will also be inherited, provided that the subclass itself doesn't have a `@PostConstruct` method. There can namely be only one. So if the subclass itself has a `@PostConstruct`, then the superclass' one won't be invoked.

So if you override the `@PostConstruct` in the subclass, then you'd need to explicitly invoke the superclass' one.

```
public class SuperBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

```java
@ManagedBean
public class SubBean extends SuperBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        // ...
    }

}
```

Alternatively, provide an abstract method which the subclass must implement (without `@PostConstruct`!).

```
public class SuperBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void superInit() {
        // ...
        init();
    }

    public abstract void init();

}
```

```java
@ManagedBean
public class SubBean extends SuperBean {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Another option would be to give the `@PostConstruct` annotated methods different names in the superclass and the subclass. Then you don't need to call the superclass method explicitly.

Comment: @Matt: Are you talking about omitting the `super` keyword, or the whole `super.init()` call?

Comment: The whole `super.init()` call. It works im my scenario (See my comment to the question).

Comment: @Matt: OP is managing beans by JSF, not by CDI. That might be the difference. JSF doesn't invoke multiple `@PostConstruct` methods, only the one "closest" in the class hierarchy will be invoked. I must however admit that I'm at this point not sure if this is by specification or not.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you. How the injection mechanism works is still a mystery to me but i'm glad it works the way I need it to.